# Single line formatting CSS with line break at certain length/column

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

**Cutting to the chase:**

Is there an option in VS or a plugin that can provide the ability to insert a line break after a certain amount of columns of a compressed/single line formatted Razor/HTML/ASPX page?

**From:**

[image]

**To:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> CSS -> Formatting

choose style: Compact rules

Answer (score 1):

You can use resharper a visual studio plugin.

If you go to `ReSharper -> Options -> Languages -> C# -> Formatting style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping`

There is a host of options in there.

Answer (score 0):

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Word Wrap`

or if you prefer:

<kbd>Ctrl+E+W</kbd>